# Sorting data in memory using AARCH64?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, arm64

Address -----M[X6]  -----M[X6+8]    -----M[X6+16]-------    M[X6+24]    --------M[X6+32]

Data----------- 740 ---------  811-----------    492----------------          773----------------         424

How could I sort this data using only STUR and LDUR and only 10 lines?

```
LDUR X7,[X6,#8]
LDUR X8,[X6,#0]
STUR X7,[X6,#0]
STUR X8,[X6,#8]
LDUR X7,[X6,#32]
LDUR X8,[X6,#0]
STUR X7,[X6,#0]
STUR X8,[X6,#32]
LDUR X7,[X6,#16]
LDUR X8,[X6,#8]
STUR X7,[X6,#8]
STUR X8,[X6,#16]
```

I could just do 3 swaps like this, but that would be 12 lines.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to swap elements. If you have 5 registers available, just load all 5 items and write them out into the correct locations. That's exactly 10 lines.

Comment: Or sort into descending order so you can leave `424` at the end.  BTW, you can use even fewer instructions if you use `ldp` or `stp` (load-pair and/or store-pair) to load or store 2 registers at once.

Comment: And when sorting in ascending order, you can leave `773` where it is.